# How to convert a UTC timestamp to local day, hour, minute in Java?

Tags: java, datetime

Given then timestamp 1245613885 that is a timestamp in GMT

How do I turn that into Year, Day, Hour, Minute values in Java using the server's local timezone info?

Comment: Similar: [*Java How to convert UTC milliseconds into UTC Date*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33430787/642706)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`java.util.Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for this. It offers a [`setTimeZone()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) method (which is by the way superfluous since it by default already picks the system default timezone).

```
long timestamp = 1245613885;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp * 1000);

int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

If you'd like to present it in a human readable date string, then I'd suggest [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dateString = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
System.out.println(dateString); // 2009-06-21 15:51:25
```

*(the output is correct as per my timezone GMT-4)*

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Calendar;  
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Example{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      long utcTimestamp = 1285578547L;
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
      cal.setTimeInMillis(utcTimestamp * 1000);
      System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
      System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
      System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
      System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
      System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
      System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like Joda Time which is much faster than the JDK Date/Calendar classes and also doesn't have thread-safety issues with date parsing (not that your question relates to date parsing)

Comment: +1, if only to express solidarity with the 99.99% of the human race who want the existing JDK calendar stuff to die a fiery death.  --JA

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need a formatter to do this

Date date = new Date(1245613885L*1000);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant                                        // Represent a moment in UTC.
.ofEpochMilli( 1_245_613_885L )                // Parse a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
.atZone(                                       // Adjust from UTC to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" )                  // Or "America/Chicago" etc.
)                                              // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.format(                                       // Generate text representing the value of our `ZonedDateTime` object.
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )   // Automatically localize the format and content of the string being generated.
    .withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )        // Or Locale.US etc.
)                                              // Returns a `String` object.
```

> jeudi 15 janvier 1970 à 19 h 00 min 13 s heure normale du Japon

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible date-time classes as of the adoption of JSR 310.

If your input `1245613885` is count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC, then parse as an `Instant` (a moment in UTC).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_245_613_885L ) ;
```

Generate a string representing the value of that `Instant` object using standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

Adjust from UTC to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region( a time zone).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Apply a `ZoneId` to the `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment as the `instant`, but different wall-clock time.
```

Generate a string representing the value of that `ZonedDateTime` object using standard ISO 8601 format extended to append the name of the zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

For other formats, either specify your own custom formatting pattern or let *java.time* automatically localize. For either route, use `DateTimeFormatter`. Search Stack Overflow as this has been handled many times already.

Answer (score -1):

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"), Locale.US);
calendar.setTimeInMillis(1245613885 * 1000);
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Change the `TimeZone` value you're passing into the `Calendar` object's constructor if you need a different time zone.

Comment: UTC timestamps are represented as seconds from the epoch.  java.util.Calendar uses milliseconds from the epoch so you need to multiply by 1000 when setting the time on Calendar.

Comment: You can use `@nickname` to target a comment on someone so that s/he will be notified about the comment in the global inbox and recent activity. Note that this is unnecessary when you're the questioner or answerer yourself :) See also [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have/35913#35913) on meta.