# Java How to convert UTC milliseconds into UTC Date

Tags: java, utc

I have an int 1446159600 which is UTC/GMT date Thu, 29 Oct 2015 23:00:00 GMT.  I tried to do conversion to the actual UTC date, but couldn't get it to work with Calendar, SimpleDateFormat, and Timezone classes.  Can someone help me?

Comment: What Java version? 7? 8?

Comment: It seems the timestamp is in seconds, java works in milliseconds. Keep that in mind.

Comment: Similar: [*How to convert a UTC timestamp to local day, hour, minute in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3843080/642706)

Answer (score 2):

## to;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochSecond ( 1_446_159_600L )
```

> 2015-10-29T23:00:00Z

## Count From Epoch

You appear to have an integer count-from-[epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) counting whole seconds with an epoch of [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), the first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

The old date-time classes you reference are based on milliseconds. So multiply by 1,000.

## java.time

Even better, avoid those old classes altogether. The new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework in Java 8 and later is a vast improvement, supplanting those old classes. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). These new classes have a resolution of [nanoseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), or 9 decimal places in a fraction of a second.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class (a moment on the timeline in UTC) even has a handy [`ofEpochSecond`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) method, so no need to multiply by a thousand.

```
long wholeSecondsFromEpochInUtc = 1_446_159_600L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond ( wholeSecondsFromEpochInUtc );
```

That solves your Question in a one-liner.

## Formatting

We can go further. Apply a time zone to that Instant to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneId );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime ( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale ( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
String output = zdt.format ( formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "instant (UTC): " + instant );
System.out.println ( "zdt: " + zdt );
System.out.println ( "output: " + output );
```

> instant (UTC): 2015-10-29T23:00:00Z
>
> zdt: 2015-10-29T19:00-04:00[America/Montreal]
>
> output: jeudi 29 octobre 2015 19 h 00 EDT

Comment: Sorry I am using java 7.

Comment: @user270811 See the *ThreeTen-Extra* project for Java 6 & 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
// print the time in local time zone
        Date date = new Date(1446159600);
        System.out.println(date);

        // print UTC time 
        TimeZone utcTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(utcTimeZone);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(utcTimeZone);
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());

        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

        //print in local time zone 
        //Because getTime method actully call new Date(long millsecond);

        /* public final Date getTime() {
                return new Date(getTimeInMillis());
            }*/
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp seems to be in seconds while most java uses milliseconds so we have to multiply by 1000.

```
    long timestampMilliseconds = 1446159600*1000L;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String stringDate = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(timestampMilliseconds));
    System.out.println(stringDate); // Thu, 29 Oct 2015 23:00:00 GMT
```

The L after 1000 is so that the multiplication is done as long values and the number does not overflow integer max value. You can use `((long)1446159600)*1000`, `1446159600L*1000` or whatever to get the same effect. You can use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1446159600)` too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually 1446159600 milliseconds is "Sat Jan 17 23:12:39 IST 1970". IST being my local time.

But, you can get the date associated using a Calendar object like follows.

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(1446159600 );
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

And, the output in this happens to be "Sat Jan 17 23:12:39 IST 1970"

Also, if you want to convert the milliseconds to a date, you can use http://currentmillis.com/
It gives the date associated with the given millisecs.

Comment: That's interesting, if I go to http://www.epochconverter.com/, and put in this number, I get 10/29/2015.  Does this mean unix epoch time is different than UTC time in milliseconds?

Comment: It looks like 'epochconverter' takes seconds instead of milliseconds. That's the problem :D

Comment: For some reason the time returned is in PDT

Comment: Do you live in that time zone?

Comment: sorry, I am trying to avoid local timezone, UTC time only as Date and not as string.

Comment: @user270811 Then may be you can try converting the date to an Instant. Instant always shows the time in UTC.
You can refer to the question i asked on this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435491/toinstant-in-calendar-is-showing-in-gmt-instead-of-local-time/33444673#33444673

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but this creates a Date from the current time in milliseconds:

```
public class DateTime
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis ();
    System.out.println (time);
    Date date = new Date (time);
    System.out.println (date);
  }
}
```

which outputs:

```
1446191239738
Fri Oct 30 18:47:19 AEDT 2015
```

Comment: But I want to confirm it's in UTC timezone.  Thanks.

Comment: @user270811 but it's just a long integer, you already said it was a UTC date.

Comment: this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Check this code out:

```
    // Make a format for showing the date
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyy", Locale.FRANCE);
    // Make a format for showing the time
    DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.FRANCE);

    // Get the current time in UTC (in milliseconds since 01 Jan 1970)
    Long currentUTCDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

    // Convert the current time from UTC to normal date
    Date currentDate = new Date(currentUTCDate);

    // Take the date only from currentDate object using the dateFormat we made before
    // and pass it to currentDateOnly String
    String currentDateOnly = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
    // Do the same with the time
    String currentTimeOnly = timeFormat.format(currentDate);
```

In this code we can distinguish three main different classes:
1. `SimpleDateFormat()`, which returns an object of type `DateFormat`
2. `Calendar`, whcih one of it methods is `getTimeInMillis()`
3. `Date`, which makes an object that can hold every detail about the time you gave it

Now:
. The `getTimeInMillis()` returns a number of type Long, which holds the current number of milliseconds since 01 Jan 1970.
We use this type of Time to make it easier for making calculations with dates.
. In `Date` class, we have a constructor that takes our Long number from `getTimeInMillis()` as a parameter, and returns for us an object of type `Date` that holds every detail of the Time we gave it in the constructor.
. Now we don't need all the details that our object `currentDate` holds, so we make a filter to take only date and time from the `currentDate` object, and to accomplish that we use objects of type `DateFormat`.
. Making an object of type `DateFormat`, we use `SimpeDateFormat()` constructor and we pass to it a `parameter` as a `String` of a specific `pattern` that we want to take from our `currentDate` object, for example ("dd MMM, yyy"), which is in our code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyy", Locale.FRANCE);
```

. Finally we take our `currentDate` object as a `paremeter` to our `dateFormat.format()` method, which will return to us a String of a filtered Date of the same pattern we gave it, which is in our example `"dd MMM, yyy"`, and the result will look something like:
`08 Sep, 2018`

Comment: More expaination please.

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Suggesting their use in 2018 is poor advice.

Comment: Well, I am very new here and I couldn't find something better

Comment: Well, I apologize for giving useless informations. Thanks for passing by