# toInstant() in Calendar is showing in GMT instead of Local time

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

I am trying to convert a Calendar instance to instant and i am doing that as follows

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    Instant inst = cal.toInstant();
    System.out.println(inst.toString());
```

And, the output for it is as follows

> Fri Oct 30 17:23:40 IST 2015
>
> 2015-10-30T11:53:40.037Z

So, my question is about the difference in the outputs from the Calendar and the instant. The output from the instant is in GMT instead of the local time.
I have not seen any documentation that says that Instant class only gives the date in GMT. So, i am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33436416/642706) by Rawat is correct. An `Instant` is always in UTC by definition.

The format of the string representation generated by the `toString` method is standard, defined by ISO 8601.

The `Instant` class is part of the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. The new classes in this framework supplant the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes from the early days of Java.

Avoid the old classes as they are notoriously troublesome. Do not mix up the old and new. The conversion methods such as `toInstant` are intended only for use when interoperating with old code has not yet been updated for the new types.

To adjust an `Instant` into a time zone, specify the time zone via a `ZoneId` object to produce a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

Do not be confused by the "Local" in `LocalDateTime` class. That class represents the vague idea of a date-time. It does *not* apply to any particular time zone and is therefore not tied to the timeline.

Answer (score 3):

> Invoking toString on an Instant produces output like the following:
>
> 2013-05-30T23:38:23.085Z
>
> This format follows the ISO-8601 standard for representing date and
>   time.

Have a look at:

- [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/instant.html)
- [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class documentation